# Base Case in in Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

What is the consequence of not proving a base case in mathematical induction?
For example:

prove that 2 + 4 + · · · + 2n = (n + 2)(n − 1) for any integer
n ≥ 2

if a student jumped right into the inductive step without proving the base case
**We assume that P(n) : 2 + 4 + · · · + 2n = (n + 2)(n − 1), and we want to
prove P(n + 1) : 2 + 4 + · · · + 2n + 2(n + 1) = (n + 3)n.
2 + 4 + · · · + 2n + 2(n + 1) = 2 + 4 + · · · + 2n + 2n + 2
= (n + 2)(n − 1) + 2n + 2 hypothesis
= n(n + 2) − (n + 2) + 2n + 2
= n(n + 2) + n
= n(n + 3)**

What does this say?

Comment: here the base case is true but the student did not include that in their proof. From a markers point of view can we assume their proof is invalid/incomplete or just pass it? How important is that step @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: I marked such problems on a scale of $10$. I’d have given $7$ for that if the intrusive *hypothesis* had not been (mis)placed in the middle of the chain of equalities and $6$ as it stands. In general $7$ meant that it was mostly right, but there was some non-trivial error or omission. I would probably also have written a note on the paper showing how essentially the same argument could be used to ‘prove’ that $\sum_{k=1}^n2k=(n+2)(n-1)+1$.